# QGIS Field Calculator - Aggregating and Calculating Ratios Based on Y-coordinate

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, spatial-query, aggregation

I am trying to use the QGIS Field Calculator to calculate the sum of a specific attribute ('demo_field') for features in a layer to the sum of the same attribute for features that share the same y-coordinate. However, I am encountering an issue with the following expression:

```
aggregate(layer:= 'layer_name', aggregate:='sum', expression:='demo_field', filter:= y(@geometry)=y(geometry(@parent)))
```

The error message is "Eval Error: Could not calculate aggregate for: 'demo_Field' (Cannot calculate sum on string values)."

How can I correctly calculate the sum of the attribute for each feature based on the y-coordinate?

Also, what if I dont want to give the 'layer_name' but want the current layer to be used without specifying the 'layer_name'? The reason for this is I also want to use this expression in graphical modeler.

Comment: Column data type was the first thing I checked after I received that error. 
I just figured out that if the column name is written without inverted comma, this works.

Comment: Indeed! Single quotes `'` are used for textstrings. Fieldnames are used with double quotes `"` or without any quotes at all.

Comment: Oops, Thank you. This is new for me as I am still learning to use expression. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The column name should not be in inverted comma. The correct solution would be:

```
aggregate(
    layer:= @layer, 
    aggregate:='sum',
    expression:= demo_field,
    filter:= y(@geometry)=y(geometry(@parent))
)
```

This worked for me here. Also, it will be necessary to check the data type of column. If it is in string, its better to convert using `to_real()` or `to_int()`.